# How to add overlay on the Camera using ZBAR in Android

Tags: java, android, overlay, zbar

I need help, I am using ZBAR for bar code scanning for the Android App. I want to add a overlay on the camera view so that I can display some information and get user input using button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the help of SurfaceView For More Info U Can Check This [Click](http://www.android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to add overlay on the SurfaceView. I have added it inside the ZBAR lib ZBarScannerActivity.OnCreate